# OpenLayers/Mapnik map layers dont show up when put in a Yii view file

Tags: php, yii, openlayers, openstreetmap, mapnik

I am trying to integrate a php file which has been written by another programmer in my yii web application by adding this code to my view file:

```
    include 'folder/myfile.php';
```

folder is in the same directory with my web app, no problems with directories, also all javascript files needed are linked in myfile.php including OpenLayers.js.

and myfile.php has the following code for displaying the map based on mapnik and osm tiles:

```
    <body onload="init();">
        <div style="width:40%; height:90%;" id="map"> </div>
```

init() is a function in a javascript file linked in myfile.php and has the following code:

```
    function init() {
         console.log("map initializing......");

        map = new OpenLayers.Map ("map", {
            controls:[
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({geodesic: true}),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink('permalink'),
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),                    
                new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()],
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34),
            maxResolution: 156543.0339,
            numZoomLevels: 5,
            units: 'm',
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
            displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        } );

        // This is the layer that uses the locally stored tiles
        var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Local Tiles", "tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 19});
        map.addLayer(newLayer);
        console.log("osm tiles added");

        var layerMapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("Mapnik");
        console.log(map.addLayer(layerMapnik));
        console.log("mapnik layer added");
}
```

as you can see I put console.logs so that I could check in the console if the code is actually running, and all of these console.logs are shown in my console. so init() actually runs. I also tried doing console.log(map.addLayer(newLayer)); and it shows "true" in my console

running myfile.php in localhost works totally fine and displays the map on my browser but when I did the things above mentioned so that I could also show it in my yii page, only the text and buttons in myfile.php are displayed, not the maps.

[I checked the resources tab in my developer tools and I can see that the tiles are loaded (index.php is the view file where I put include 'folder/myfile.php';](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiIkV.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I found a workaround by removing the  <!DOCTYPE html> tag in views/layouts/main.php but from what I know removing that tag will incur some bugs on how the browser displays html code

Comment: You have to register the assets properly. I guess that's the issue here